# Spring AMQP - anonymous queue declaration

Tags: java, spring, amqp, spring-amqp

I am trying to declare anonymous queue using Spring AMQP annotations, but seems it is not working.

```
@RabbitListener(
  id = "b1",
  bindings =
      @QueueBinding(
          value =
              @Queue(
                  name = "",
                  durable = "false",
                  exclusive = "true",
                  autoDelete = "true",
                  admins = "amqpAdmin1"),
          exchange =
              @Exchange(
                  value = "${my.rabbitmq[0].exchange}", declare = "false",
                  ignoreDeclarationExceptions = "true",
                  type = ExchangeTypes.TOPIC,
                  admins = "amqpAdmin1"),
          key = "*.*.*.*.*.*.*.-",
          admins = "amqpAdmin1"),
  admin = "amqpAdmin1",
  containerFactory = "lf1",
  autoStartup = "true")
```

I read that I can use empty `name` param, and it should create anonymous queue - but the thing is that I need server-generated name (I have no privileges to name my own queue). Is this possible at all with spring AMQP lib currently?

I see in the code that it currently uses

```
private String declareQueue(org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.Queue bindingQueue,
        Collection<Declarable> declarables) {
    String queueName = (String) resolveExpression(bindingQueue.value());
    boolean isAnonymous = false;
    if (!StringUtils.hasText(queueName)) {
        queueName = Base64UrlNamingStrategy.DEFAULT.generateName(); //<---- HERE
        // default exclusive/autodelete and non-durable when anonymous
        isAnonymous = true;
    }
```

but here instead of `Base64UrlNamingStrategy.DEFAULT.generateName();` -> I would need to spring to go to RabbitMQ broker and fetch RabbitMQ generated name and use that one.

**UPDATE**

```
@Bean
  public Queue q2(){
    Queue q = QueueBuilder.nonDurable().exclusive().autoDelete().build();
    //Queue q = new Queue("", false, true, true); --> same
    q.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(amqpAdmin2());
    return q;
  }

  @Bean
  public Exchange e2(@Value("${my.rabbitmq[1].exchange}") String name){
    Exchange e = ExchangeBuilder.topicExchange(name).ignoreDeclarationExceptions().build();
    e.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(amqpAdmin2());
    return e;
  }

  @Bean
  public Binding bin2(Queue q2, Exchange e2){
    Binding b = BindingBuilder.bind(q2).to(e2).with("*.*.*.*.*.*.*.-").noargs();
    b.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(amqpAdmin2());
    return b;
  }

  @RabbitListener(id = "b2", queues = "#{q2}",
      admin = "amqpAdmin2",
      containerFactory = "lf2", autoStartup = "true")
  public void listen2(GenericMessage<?> msg) {
    comparator.recordForComparison(props.getRabbitmq().get(1).getId(), msg.getPayload());
  }
```

and this is in the logs:

```
Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue () durable:false, auto-delete:true, exclusive:true. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
2022-02-10 09:22:43.660  INFO 30076 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.DirectMessageListenerContainer : Container initialized for queues: [spring.gen-ZAVana-pSSW2WaanrkVZXw_awaiting_declaration]
2022-02-10 09:22:43.661  INFO 30076 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: my.server.com:5671
2022-02-10 09:22:43.765 ERROR 30076 --- [           b2-1] o.s.a.r.l.DirectMessageListenerContainer : Queue not present, scheduling consumer SimpleConsumer [queue=spring.gen-ZAVana-pSSW2WaanrkVZXw_awaiting_declaration, index=0, consumerTag=null identity=3f844994] for restart
```

and this is what I added after removing `@RabbitListener`. Now it works with this:

```
@Bean
  public MessageListenerContainer c2(DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactory lf2, Queue q2){
    DirectMessageListenerContainer lc = lf2.createListenerContainer();
    lc.setQueues(q2);
    lc.setAutoStartup(true);
    MessageListenerAdapter a = new MessageListenerAdapter();
    a.setMessageConverter(converter());
    a.setDefaultListenerMethod("receive");
    a.setDelegate(new MessageReceiver(props.getRabbitmq().get(1).getId()));
    lc.setupMessageListener(a);
    lc.afterPropertiesSet();
    return lc;
  }

class MessageReceiver{

    private final int id;

    public MessageReceiver(int id){
      this.id= id;
    }

    void receive(Object o){
      comparator.recordForComparison(this.id, o);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - the `@RabbitListener` bean postprocessor grabs the name before it has been declared.

Here is a work around (manually inject the queue):

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So71033589Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So71033589Application.class, args);
    }

    @RabbitListener(id = "foo", autoStartup = "false")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}

@Configuration
class Config{

    @Bean
    Queue q() {
        return new Queue("", false, true, true);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry, Queue q) {
        return args -> {
            MessageListenerContainer container = registry.getListenerContainer("foo");
            ((AbstractMessageListenerContainer) container).setQueues(q);
            container.start();
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this one should be treated as a bug and missing part when we implemented this https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-816. So, with regular `Queue` bean definition you are able to set the name to empty string and the `actualName` is going to be set after declaration on the broker via `RabbitAdmin`.

Consider that as a workaround for your use-case. You must move this `@QueueBinding` to the `Binding`, `Queue` and `Exchange` bean definitions. And then you just use `queues = "#{myQueueBean}"`. See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#builder-api.

Please, raise a GH issue for this bug and we will fix it soon.

Comment: I think it now created anonymous queue (as per your instructions), but container still tries to use that `spring.gen` name instead of server-generated: `Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue () durable:false, auto-delete:true, exclusive:true.  Container initialized for queues: [spring.gen-BOzHX1TqSkKYOGhdE2Khag_awaiting_declaration]
ERROR 33388 --- [           b2-1] o.s.a.r.l.DirectMessageListenerContainer : Queue not present, scheduling consumer SimpleConsumer `

Comment: Did you remove the `@QueueBinding`? Edit the question to show your new configuration (and comment here that you have done so).

Comment: yes. removed that. In the end, I created manually MessageListeners as beans, and completely removed those annotations. Now it works...

Comment: @Gary Russell I removed "binding=" and used "queues=" as in Artem's answer. It still tried that spring.gen queue.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. We can't help without seeing the code.

Comment: @GaryRussell It doesn't, but it is how it works :) I guess that `@RabbitListener` annotation sees that queue name is `""` and it just uses that `Base64UrlNamingStrategy.DEFAULT.generateName()`, while actually queue name was generated on the server...

Comment: @GaryRussell btw I updated the code, so that you can see the setup.

Comment: Thanks - something has broken it - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1422

Comment: I found the problem - I have added an answer with a work around.